# Indexing failed for null value

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have created an index with a Edm.String field. According to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types), string is by default a nullable type. However, when I try to index a json object with the property set to null, it gives me exception:

> The request is invalid. Details: parameters : A null value was found with the expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]'. The expected type 'Edm.String[Nullable=False]' does not allow null values.

One follow up question is that when searching, how to differentiate between [field is null] and [field eq '']?

I'm using the Rest endpoint to post data, using api version "2017-11-11-Preview" as we use some of the new features.

The payload for creating the index is something like below:
`PUT https://***.search.windows.net//indexes/acmnotificationindex?api-version=2017-11-11-Preview HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
{
  "name": "index",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "TestId",
      "type": "Edm.Int64"
    },
    {
      "name": "TestTitle",
      "type": "Edm.String"
    }]
}`

And the http payload for se to index is just a json with `{TestTitle:null}`

Comment: Can you please share the exact request payload and URL you're using to index the data (without api-keys)?

Comment: Is {MyField:null} literally the JSON payload you're sending to the Index API? That API takes an array, so I'd expect something more like {"value":[{"MyField":null}]}. Can you please clarify?

Comment: I could not repro this in later test, the error seems from OData, not the actual azure search service, but still the behavior is unexpected as I couldn't think of a reason why it shows Nullable=False for string type